# On PHP form, drop down list displays wrong data from .txt file

Tags: php, forms, dropdown

I looked at related posts on this and saw one that now has me thinking I've done this incorrectly.  I'm very, very new to PHP but willing to learn.

I need to have an index.php form with an input box for Student Name, and input box for Student Number and a drop down list of courses.

My PHP scripts are not allowed to contain data - the data must be retrieved from .txt files which are not optional.

I have courses.txt that has four course names, each with thier own unique course code and the max number of people that can enrol.  Contents of courses.txt:
Animation Film Design:AFD-250:6
Digital Sculpture:DS-410:4
History of Animation:HA-240:6
Visual Effects:VE-298:4

I have coursesfinal.txt which has been converted to a comma delimited file.  Contents of coursesfinal.txt:
Animation Film Design,AFD-250,6
Digital Sculpture,DS-410,4
History of Animation,HA-240,6
Visual Effects,VE-298,4

Currently the two input boxes work fine.  My problem is with the drop down list.  I would like it to display the course name then a space and then the course code.  At this time it displays the course code only.  I also don't understand why it is displaying the second field of data.

Thank you.

index.php code...

```html
<?php
// Convert courses.txt file to comma delimited file coursesfinal.txt
 $in = "courses.txt";
 $out = "coursesfinal.txt";

 $IN = fopen ($in, 'r') or die ("$in cannot be opened for reading.");
 $OUT = fopen ($out, 'w') or die ("$out cannot be opened for writing.");

 if (flock($OUT, LOCK_EX)) {
    while ($inline = fgets ($IN) ) {
       $splitarray = explode (":", $inline);
       $outline = implode(",", $splitarray);
       fputs ($OUT, $outline);
    }
    flock($OUT, LOCK_UN);
 }

 fclose ($IN);
 fclose ($OUT);
 
// Search coursesfinal.txt file for course to match user input
 $datafile = "coursesfinal.txt";

 // If selection has been made, find a match
 if (isset ($_POST['courses'])) {
    $courses = strip_tags ($_POST['']);
    $DB = fopen ($datafile, 'r') or die ("$datafile cannot be opened for reading.");

    $found = FALSE;
    while ($record = fgets ($DB) and ! $found) {
       $field = explode (",", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
       $found = $courses === $field[0];
    }

    fclose ($DB);

    if ($found) {
       echo "<p>You have selected: $field[0] $field[1]</p>\n";
    }
 }






?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<style>
body{background-color: #ffffe6; width:610px;}
h1 {color: #29a3a3;}
.inputbox {padding: 7px; border:  #F0F0F0 2px solid; border-radius: 4px;}
.btn {padding: 10px;background-color: #29a3a3; border: solid thin #000000; color: #FFF; font-weight: bolder; cursor: pointer;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Course Registration</h1>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">

        <fieldset><legend><strong>Student Information</strong></legend>
            <dl>
            <dt>Student Name:</dt>
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentname" type="text" id="studentname" required autofocus placeholder="Please enter your first and last name" tabindex="10" size="50"></dd>
            <br>
            <br>
            <dt for="number">Student Number:</dt>
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentnumber" type="text" required id="studentnumber" placeholder="Please enter using the following format: PX-03-046" tabindex="20" size="50"></dd>
            </dl>
            <br>
        </fieldset> 
        <br>
        
        <fieldset><legend><strong>Available Courses</strong></legend>  
        <br>  
        

Select a Course: <select name="course"> 
    <option value="-1" selected>Select From...</option> 
<?php
// Generate the form 
$DB = fopen ($datafile, 'r') or die ("$datafile cannot be opened for reading."); 
while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) { 
$field = explode (",", htmlentities (trim ($record))); 
echo " <option value=\"$field[0]\">$field[1]</option>\n"; 
} 
fclose ($DB); 

echo " </select>\n"; 


?>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>                               
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        <p>
            <input name="reset" type="reset" tabindex="40" value="Clear Form" class="btn">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" tabindex="50" value="Submit Form" class="btn">
        </p>
    </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your following code:

```
while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) { 
   $field = explode (",", htmlentities (trim ($record))); 
   echo " <option value=\"$field[0]\">$field[1]</option>\n"; 
}
```

If you call `fgets()` with one parameter then, it keeps reading until it finds newline character or EOF (whichever comes first). Make sure you format coursesfinal.txt such as:

```
Animation Film Design,AFD-250
6 Digital Sculpture,DS-410
4 History of Animation,HA-240,
6 Visual Effects,VE-298
```

and then you can

```
while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) { 
   $field = explode (",", htmlentities (trim ($record))); 
   echo " <option value=\"$field[1]\">$field[0] $field[1]</option>\n"; 
}
```

Note that `explode()` with coma delimiter will split string "Animation Film Design,AFD-250" into array

```
$field[0] == "Animation Film Design"
$field[1] == "AFD-250"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me out.  The data in my coursesfinal.txt file looks similar to yours.  Four rows and each row has the course name, course code and max enrolment number with a comma between the name, code and max number.

Comment: I amended my code to what you provided and it's displaying exactly as I wanted it to.  Thank you!  The hours of Googling and youtube videos - and I couldn't find an answer but still learned.

Comment: When it comes to sanitization and validation, I should do that for both input boxes and the option selected from the drop down list correct?

Comment: After correcting my code with the above suggestion the drop down list displayed all four options. I moved 1 line of code to where I think it should be and the list now only displays the 4th option. New Code[php]<fieldset><legend><strong>Course Selection</strong></legend>  
        <br>  
            Select a Course:<select name="courses" tabindex="30">\n"; 
            <option value="-1" >Available Courses...</option> <?php echo " <option value=\"$field[1]\">$field[0] $field[1]</option>\n"; ?>
            
            </select> [/php]